# how to tell with perforce if you are logged in with -a or just a host login?

Tags: perforce

I'd like a method to detect if the current login is limited to a host, or is valid across all hosts. This is needed for error detection when using things like LSF.

I'm aware of p4 login -s, but I haven't figured out how to tell the difference between -a and per host

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user's password (or are a superuser) you can run `login` again with different flags to see what the ticket values are with different host limits -- running `login` when you already have a valid ticket does not generate a new ticket, it just returns the existing (server-side) ticket with the appropriate hashing.  (`p4 logout -a` invalidates the server-side ticket.)

So for example, if I have this ticket and want to figure out whether it's host-bound:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 tickets
localhost:unknown (Samwise) 18D5A046F46601FD67827A39D6449A7E
```

as a superuser I can do:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 login -h 1.2.3.4 -p Samwise
22B95BDC5DE0571C2BF92A1E688C97E3

C:\Perforce\test>p4 login -h 127.0.0.1 -p Samwise
2ECEA5DDFFEB53E4DAFA29F70DD321A4

C:\Perforce\test>p4 login -a -p Samwise
18D5A046F46601FD67827A39D6449A7E
```

Note that the ticket I got with `login -a` matches the one in my ticket file, so I know that my current ticket is a global ticket.  (The ticket values I got from `login -h` are the same ticket value hashed with the provided host.)

If I'm not a superuser, I can't use the `p4 login USERNAME` shortcut and will have to re-enter my password for each `login` command.

Comment: this command would be run by normal users so it can't have superuser access. it is however the user checking on themselves. would that work in this context (granted I'm going to try that after I finish typing this)?

Comment: As long as they're okay with entering their password each time -- as a normal user you need to re-enter the password each time you login, even if it's only refreshing your local copy of the ticket.

Comment: I'd rather not keep having them entering their passwords.  doesn't seem like there's a good way to do this.

Comment: I don't have a good sense of the context where you need this, but if it's for use in automation I'd implement a centralized service that runs with `super` permission that a user can invoke to ask about the status of their ticket (i.e. given a username and ticket, the service queries the ticket status and returns whether it's host-bound or not).

Comment: yeah. that may be the way to go.